# Why \leaders and \mkern works strangely in different font size?

Tags: fontsize, tex-core, tocloft, kerning, leaders

I can hardly determine a good title for this question, I'm sorry.

Minimal test code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
foo
{\fontsize{18}{18}\leaders\hbox{$\mkern 10000mu.\mkern 10000mu$}\hfill}
bar

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If I compile this, `bar` and the result of `\lipsum` is gone. It's amazing. And,

- If I replace the arguments of `\fontsize` with 15 or 20, everything is correct!
- If I replace `\hbox{$\mkern 10000mu.\mkern 10000mu$}` to something else, e.g. delete one `\mkern 10000mu`, the result may be correct too.

I know that `\fontsize` changes the length of a mu unit. But I totally cannot understand what happens.

Here is an example of Plain TeX:

```
% fine
% Width of hbox less than \maxdimen
a\leaders\hbox{\kern8000pt.\kern8000pt}\hfill b

text text
\vfill\eject

% BAD: text after the leaders is gone
% Width of hbox more than \maxdimen
a\leaders\hbox{\kern10000pt.\kern10000pt}\hfill b

text text
\vfill\eject

% fine?
% Width of hbox more than \maxdimen
a\leaders\hbox{\kern12000pt.\kern12000pt}\hfill b

text text
\vfill\eject

\bye
```

I wonder why a box of 20000pt width makes wrong output, but a box of 24000pt width seems correct. I know it is an overflow thus it cannot be a bug of TeX, but what happens?

---

**Background**

The code comes from `tocloft` package. Now I believe it is a bug of `tocloft`. In `tocloft`, it defines

```
\providecommand{\cftdotfill}[1]{%
  \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern #1 mu\hbox{\cftdot}\mkern #1 mu$}\hfill}
```

And `\cftnodots` is `10000`. Then this test file fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\fontsize{16}{19}\cftdotfill{\cftnodots}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\contentsline{section}{TEST}{1}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I can fix the bug by redefining `\cftdotfill` to

```
\renewcommand{\cftdotfill}[1]{%
  \leaders\hbox to #1\p@{\hss\cftdot\hss}\hfill}
```

But the bug still shocked me.

Answer (score 10):

The width of

```
\hbox{$\mkern10000mu.\mkern10000mu$}
```

is 16003.67247pt when the font used by LaTeX is at 14.4pt; when you ask for 17.28pt size, the box becomes 19204.52904pt wide, which is more than `\maxdimen` and so everything goes awry.

Notice that `\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont` (the `\selectfont` is implicitly done when the formula begins) chooses, with the standard font, a font at 17.8pt.

When you ask for 15pt, the font chosen is at 14.4pt.

It's quite bizarre that with `\fontsize{20}{20}` the behavior is normal (the box is 23050.07462pt wide). But I think it's just a curiosity.

I'd say it's an oversight in **tocloft**.

If I load **lmodern** (that has scalable fonts), the limit between regular and awry is at 14.68181pt = 962187sp; at 14.68182pt = 962188sp the behavior is the strange one.

The behavior remains strange until the font size is 19.85608pt = 1301288sp and resumes to normal at 19.85609pt = 1301289sp.

### Workaround for tocloft

One way to avoid the problem is to redefine `\cftnodots`:

```
\renewcommand\cftnodots{100mu\gobbleeight}
\newcommand\gobbleeight[8]{}
```

In this way, `\cftdotfill{\cftnodots}` will expand to

```
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \cftnodots mu\hbox{\cftdot}\mkern \cftnodots mu$}\hfill
```

and the first `\mkern` will expand the first `\cftnodots`, resulting in

```
\mkern100mu\gobbleeight mu\hbox{\cftdot}\mkern \cftnodots mu
```

and counting arguments we see that this eventually gives

```
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern100mu$}\hfill
```

which prints nothing (actually some boxes containing only white space, but it's better than an unpredictable behavior). The code in **tocloft** should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I can imagine that the width of box is wider than `\maxdimen` and something goes wrong. But I still cannot understand the difference between `\fontsize{18}{18}` and `\fontsize{20}{20}`. I'll try to make a plain TeX example.

Comment: @LeoLiu It's quite strange indeed; I'm doing experiments.